# How to read hexadecimal data from text file and write in into memory in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I have a text file named "Hex_data.txt". I want to load content of Hex_data.txt into a variable name RAM in verilog. When I try this, I get an error that the text file can't be found. Where is this file loaded from?

The content of "hex_data.txt" :

```
21           
a4         
2a         
26         
7a         
ff          
6f
```

I want to create a variable name "RAM" defined like:

reg [6:0] RAM; in which the above content save like:

```
RAM[0]=21    
RAM[1]=a4          
RAM[2]=2a            
RAM[3]=26           
RAM[4]=7a            
RAM[5]=ff            
RAM[6]=6f
```

I wrote a code:

```
module file_read;   
  reg [7:0] RAM [0:6];       
  initial $readmemh("Hex_data.txt", RAM);
  integer i;            
  initial begin               
    $display("data:");           
    for (i=0; i < 7; i=i+1)         
      $display("%d:%h",i,RAM[i]);           
  end                
endmodule
```

But the above code not working. How can i get desired output?

Comment: You could use excel. Load the file, add another column counting 0,1,2... another row with: ="RAM["&A2&"]="&A1  Then copy-paste that block into the design file. You could use bash todo a similar thing, or python,perl...  OR do you want to wrap it all in verilog?

Comment: http://verilog.renerta.com/mobile/source/vrg00016.htm Watch here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xilinx presented this use case in the [Synthesis User Guide for Vivado UG901](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2015_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf#page=126) on page 126. This example also works for the Xilinx ISE tool chain, but I don't know the User Guide number.

The essential part of code is this:

```
reg [31:0] ram [0:63];

initial begin
  $readmemh("rams_init_file.data", ram);
end
```

There are two read functions:
 - $readmemb -> binary
 - $readmemh -> hexadecimal

Answer (score 1):

```
module file_read;
reg [7:0] RAM [0:6];
initial
$readmemh("hex_data.txt", RAM);integer i;
initial begin for(i=0;i<7;i=i+1)             
$display ("RAM[%d]=%h",i,RAM[i]); end  endmodule
```